# Change the default for dragging files to a different volume

Tags: finder

When dragging files and folders to a different volume the Finder makes a copy by default. I know that I can press <kbd>command</kbd> to move instead of copy.

Is it possible to change the default and always move instead of copy?

Comment: Check this : https://superuser.com/a/1406929

Comment: @Udhy I don't see how the answer adds something to my question. I already know about the keyboard shortcut, I want to change (if possible) the default.